# Querying an array using SQL in Studio 3T for MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, robo3t, studio3t

Using Studio 3T's SQL functionaliy, how do you query into the elements of an array stored within a document?

[image: Studio 3T screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change

```
select member
```

by

```
select member.child
```

In mongoDB, this is how we get elements from an object inside a document. It could work for an array.